# How to store array in a matrix in multiple run time

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I was trying to make a matlab code to store arrays in it. I want to create a matrix of 5 rows and 3900 columns to store five different arrays in it. 
Each time I run my matlab code it should store the array in the first empty row and next time I run the code the matrix should store the new array in the second empty row and so on until all five rows are occupied by five different arrays.

here is my code :

```
matrix = zeros(5,3900);
k=1;
d=5;
if k<=d
matrix(k,:) = Array;
k=k+1;
end
```

this code does not give my what I want

even this one does not do the correct job as I described above

```
matrix = zeros(5,3900);
k=1;
if (k<=5)
matrix(k,:) = Array;
k=k+1;
end
```

and this

```
matrix = zeros(5,3900);
for k=1:5
    matrix(k,:) = Array;
end
```

What should I do to store one array of size 1*3900 in only one row in the first time and in the next run I want that the another array stores in the second row and so on until row number 5?

thank you all

Comment: You need `matrix(k,:)` rather than the (typo) `matrix(d,:)` in your last example

Comment: yes it was a careless mistakes

Comment: but it still does not give me the wanted result

Comment: You have to change `Array` each iteration if you want a different array in each loop. Where does `Array` come from?

Comment: look at the code here please http://paste.ofcode.org/vPdg8W8bmb6Gm7AvfnYi72

Comment: That code doesn't actually assign *anything* to `Array`. Please tell me (in words) why the code above doesn't work. It is placing `Array` (all zeros) into each row of `matrix`. How is what you want different?

Comment: in my code I have save(output_file, 'Array');
the Array is a vector of size 1*3900 .. i want to run the code 5 times in each time the code create a new vector (array) so then I want to store it in a matrix of size 5*3900

Comment: So you want to run the entire code 5 times? Then you don't want to loop through and replace every row with `Array` because you're overwriting the whole thing with the latest `Array` values. Instead specify an index which indicates how many times you've run your program and use that instead of `k` above

Comment: do u mean that i do so in the first run matrix(1,:) then second run matrix(2,:) and so on until matrix(5,:) ?

Comment: or is it like this `k=1;
matrix = zeros(5,3900);
matrix(k,:) = Array;
k=k+1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to run the code several times, but each time the `array` is different, which is filling up the matrix.
In your example you're overwriting `matrix` and `k` each time you run the code and that's (if I understand you right) is preventing from correct execution. What you could do is something like:

1. initialize before you run the first time your code:  `matrix = zeros(5,3900);`and `k=1;`
2. Run afterwards your first code without `matrix = zeros(5,3900);
   k=1;`

In this case `matrix` and `k` should increment as you wish it.

Edit:

The first code, which you posted, will do the following (each time you run it):

1. create an matrix of size [3,3900] with all 0 -entries. if the variable `matrix` already exists, it will be completely overwritten
2. same for `k` and `d` but with 1 and 5, respectively
3. check if `k<=d`: this condition is always true because `k = 1` and `d = 5`
4. assign on the first row of `matrix` the values of `array`(first row because `k = 1`)
5. add 1 to `k`

So you see the statement #5 has no influence because each time you run your code `k` and `matrix` are overwritten.

So what you have to do is to NOT set `matrix = zeros(5,3900);
k=1;` at the begin of your code. In this way `matrix` and `k` remain the same. But you have to take care to initialize at `k` and `matrix` before you run the first time your code (if not Matlab doesn't know what `k` is)

Is this clearer now?

Micha

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: Which part did you not understand?

Comment: did u mean that the code should be so :`k=1;
matrix = zeros(5,3900);
matrix(k,:) = Array;
k=k+1;`